# Is it possible to update a mercurial repository to -1?

Tags: mercurial

I want to "clear" my working directory for the moment (less space requirements for SSD and drive backups)

Specifically, I want to know if I can update to revision -1 (so that mercurial clears everything that is not itself).

Can this be done using a mercurial command? (I'll write a script if I have too, but it's advantageous to share a command with others rather than writing scripts that do the "right" thing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run `hg update null`, it should remove everything except the `.hg` directory and any files not tracked by the repository.

If there were untracked files you can remove them as well using `hg purge`. [Purge](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PurgeExtension) is an extension but it is distributed together with mecurial so you just have to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have uncommitted changes and don't care about preserving them, `hg update -C null` will take care of getting rid of them; all you will have left after this are the `.hg` directory and untracked files.